# How to get onPrepareOptionsMenu to "toggle" my preferences class

Tags: android, preferences

**My code:**

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Preferences.class);
    startActivity(settingsActivity);
    return true;
}
```

This works to open the settings menu (`Preferences.class`) but I would like it to close the menu if it's already open when this system button is pressed. What can I add or change to make that happen?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Your question is not very clear, especially when you mention a "system button". Are you sure you are using `onPrepareOptionsMenu` properly? It should usually be used to modify the contents of the menu, not start a new activity, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)

Comment: @btse Thanks for the fast response. Sorry for the unclear question.. still new at this. I'm probably -not- using onPrepareOptionsMenu properly and that might be the issue! I implemented a custom settings menu I found at [link]http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences and I wasn't sure where to stick the call to the preferences class so I put it in the overridden onCreateOptionsMenu method. When this only worked on the first call per activity I switched to the onPrepareOptionsMenu method. What should I be using to start the new activity that holds my custom preferences menu?

Comment: You should have a "Settings" item that you should be able to select, which then takes you to your preferences class. Let me write up a response for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the menu to close by adding this to my customized preferences menu class:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        onBackPressed();
        return false;
    }
```

which calls this:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

which takes the user back to the screen to play another round. I don't know if this is an acceptable solution for every case but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how you should be implementing what you want:**

First thing first, you want to supply a "Settings" item that can selected by the user to get to your `Preferences` class. You do that by adding an item to your `menu/main.xml` and inflating it in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

**menu/main.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Settings"/>

    ...

</menu>
```

**Inside your Main Activity, override this to inflate your main.xml file:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    ...

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**And then override this to handle what happens when a `Menu` item is selected, in this case the `Settings` item:**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Preferences.class);
            startActivity(settingsActivity);
            return true;
        ...
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this! I will implement it tonight and come back to mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: thanks again for the code. I made the changes but I'm not sure this is what I wanted to do. There is now an extra step to access the menu.. the gray bar pops up at the bottom and clicking on that takes user to my custom settings menu. I liked it taking them directly to the menu. Do you know if it is bad practice to skip the inflated menu?

Comment: @CaseyMurray Sorry! I guess I didn't fully understand what you were trying to achieve. It sounds like you are developing for a phone that has an integrated menu button. You should keep in mind that a lot of phones nowadays don't have that and they rely on the three dots on the action bar to access the menu. The three dots is meant to designate that there are more options. It might make sense in your app to overlook this function and go straight to the preferences screen, but I can't say for sure. I recommend you read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html